# Init jQuery function and pass a variable with a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, object

Hardcoded i would initilize (a plugin in this case) like so, which is working:

```
var cal = $("#calendar").calendario({
    caldata : {
        '09-11-2015_1':['09-11-2015',0,19]
    }
});
```

Now i want to pass the caldata option a variable with the content like that:

```
var init_events = $("#init_events").val();

var cal = $("#calendar").calendario({
    caldata : init_events
});
```

init_events has the value `{'09-11-2015_1':['09-11-2015',0,19]}`
But that doesnt work. If I log the output of the option inside the plugin it just returns a string in the console where as if I log the first Code it logs an Object.
I tried `jQuery.parseJSON(init_events)` but this returns an Unexpected token error.

Any idea how i could get this working with passing a variable?

Comment: What's the value of `init_events`?

Comment: Can you change the format of `init_events`? JSON requires strings to use double quotes, not single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`init_events` is not valid JSON. JSON only allows double quotes around strings, not single quotes, so it should be:

```
{"09-11-2015_1":["09-11-2015",0,19]}
```

Comment: Never knew this - did some googling and found this great "validator" - http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: yes with this jQuery.parseJSON() worked and with that i was able to use it in the options, thanks! what a stupid mistake ...